# Godot 4 multiplayer sync animation tree StateMachine

Tags: animation, godot, godot4

Recently i am making a multiplayer Survival game in Godot 4. For player's animations i use Animation tree with the State Machine. The animations is simple: Start->Idle->walk->idle. My proble is that, when i past in Multiplayer Sync node the property AnimationTree:tree_root, a error raised which said that: `_process_graph: AnimationTree: root AnimationNode is not set, disabling playback.`. Also, if i didn't pass this property, the animation sync is glitchy and laggy. Have anyone any solution or any idea??

The code of player is that:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var speed = 300
@onready var animationTree  : AnimationTree = %AnimationTree
@onready var animationPlayer : AnimationPlayer = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var animationState : AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback = animationTree.get("parameters/playback")

func _enter_tree() ->void:
 set_multiplayer_authority(str(name).to_int())

func _physics_process(_delta) -> void :
 if !is_multiplayer_authority(): return
 %Camera2D.enabled = true
 #$Sprite2D.flip_h = false
 var input_direction = Input.get_vector("Left", "Right", "Up", "Down")
 velocity = input_direction * speed 
 if input_direction.x < 0:
     $Sprite2D.flip_h = true 
 if input_direction.x > 0:
     $Sprite2D.flip_h = false
 if Input.get_vector("Left", "Right", "Up", "Down")!= Vector2.ZERO:
     animationState.travel("Walk")
 else:
     animationState.travel("Idle")
 move_and_slide()
```